# Splitting single photons

Tags: photons, double-slit-experiment, photon-emission

Regarding splitting a photon, I found reference to the splitting of a high energy photon into two lower energy, entangled photons, this within the thread 'Application of splitting a photon into two'. Looking up the term 'remote entanglement' I was able to see that an electron and positron annihilate with the result of 2 entangled photons. However I've not found reference to the mechanism and measurement basis for 'annihilating a high energy photon'. This follows reading threads on the double slit experiment and its characteristic interference pattern, but being mixed in with experiments using electrons not photons. The Coudet  droplets are an interesting visualisation. But the question I have is: has a double slit experiment been done with a single photon emitter and 2 single photon detectors, one each on the 'output' of each slit, concurrently counting detections and energies?

Comment: The splitting of photons that you refer to is probably through a process called parametric down-conversion. It is a nonlinear process that occurs in nonlinear crystal under suitable circumstances.

Comment: What is the point of "concurrently counting detections and energies?" I think it can be done, but why are you looking for this?

Comment: 1)what is the nature of the source, as a single photon departs the cavity/lens 2)what intervening atoms/molecules are in between the source and the target (re directional accuracy, repeatability, and in determining if the wave packets in laser form would burn a pinhole in between the slits. 3)how close are the slits are to the would-be pinhole. 4) is there a concurrent detection by both detectors. The target represents a breakwater, the slits allowing a very small portion of the wave energy through. A gamma/x-ray photon might make the best source. &5) can the laser be seen from the side

Comment: It seems that simply two or more detectors could replace the conventional double slit target.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to split a photon. Between its emission from a subatomic particle and its absorption - also by a particle - it is an energetic quantum in which a magnetic field and an electric field oscillate in a balanced manner.

When passing through a slit, as well as when moving past an edge, the two above-mentioned field components of the photon interact with the surface electrons of the material and a deflection occurs.

It has never been observed that the wavelength of the photon has changed behind an obstacle and that would be the very first consequence of your consideration of a split photon.